# Updating listview based on sqlite query with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am having a listview with one profile imageview, two text views and a favorite imageview. 
In search box which I have provided above list view I want to query sqlite DB and get updated results populated in my listview using SimpleCursorAdapter.

The following is my create table statement which shows all columns involved.

```
public static String CREATE_TABLE_STMT="create table "
            +CONTACT_TABLE+" ("
            +ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            +NAME+" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE ,"
            +PHONE+" varchar(100) ,"
            +EMAIL+" varchar(100) ,"
            +JOBTITLE+" varchar(100) ,"
            +WEBPAGE+" varchar(100) ,"
            +PICTUREURL+" varchar(100) ,"
            +THUMBNAILURL+" varchar(100) ,"
            +PICTUREPATH+" varchar(100) ,"
            +THUMBNAILPATH+" varchar(100))";
```

I am trying to run the following query to search rows which has "NAME" matching with my search text.  To be specific I am trying to retrieve rows who's name column value starts with search query .

```
String searchQuery = "SELECT ID as _id," + AppConstants.NAME+","+AppConstants.JOBTITLE+","+AppConstants.THUMBNAILURL +  " from " + AppConstants.CONTACT_TABLE + " where " + AppConstants.NAME + " LIKE '" + query + "';";
```

- Searching for "al" should return back full row having name as "Alan"
- Searching for "tho" should return back full row having name as "Thomas"

After running the query I am checking the cursor values and trying to update my list view

```
if (cursor != null) {
            Log.i(AppConstants.APPUILOG,"cursor not null");
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String[] from = new String[] new String[] {NAME,JOBTITLE,THUMBNAILURL};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textViewMain,R.id.textViewSub,R.id.contact_icon};
            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, cursor, from, to);
            mainListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }else {
            Log.i(AppConstants.APPUILOG,"cursor is null");
        }
```

But this code is always giving back blank listview.

- Do I have to customize SimpleCursorAdapter to implement the same?
- What modification I need to do in my query?
- How to create a custom SimpleCursorAdapter and display the updated results?

Comment: see `FilterQueryPrivider` documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am getting ,You want to search in ListView .
Am I right ? If yes then you need change your approach , You don't need to interact with DB while searching in ListView . You need to implement Filters in ListView . You can see [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) link for complete solution .

Comment: Thanks @Android Dev . I was in the wrong direction. Thanks for the link and guidance.

Comment: @Harry of course you have to interact with DB while searching for data, your data are stored in DB aren't they? so how to search them if not by making a query? just read about `FilterQueryPrivider` and in your search box use `adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint)` that's all, see [here](https://codeshare.io/aFQT7) for a sample code